# What does the TEXT (5) in CREATE TABLE SQL mean when I use SQLitle?

Tags: sqlite

The  Code A is to created a SQLitle table made by SQLite Studio 3.4.3.

1: What does the `TEXT (5)` mean in SQLitle? Does it mean that the length of  *linkTitle* field can't be exceed 5 letters? What will happend if I add a record with 20 letters for *linkTitle* field?

2: The default value *"The title of saved links"* of the *linkTitle* field has exceeded 5 letters, What will happend ?

**Code A**

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    id          INTEGER   PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT,    
    linkTitle   TEXT (5)  NOT NULL
                          DEFAULT [The title of saved links],
    linkSaved   TEXT (10) NOT NULL
   
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It has no affect, the column type is considered as TEXT. SQLite accommodates much of the SQL that is used by other databases and hence the acceptance of the length specifier but ignoring (other than syntactically (omit either parenthesis and a syntax error will be issued, likewise if a non numeric is specified)).
2. No length restriction is imposed by the specifier.

If you were to use:-

```
INSERT INTO myTable (linkTitle,linkSaved) VALUES
    ('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy fence','The slow grey elephant could not jump over the fence so crashed though it'),
    (100,zeroblob(10)),
    (10.1234567,'10.1234567')
;
SELECT * FROM myTable;
```

The result would be:-

[image]

This also demonstrates that you can save (with the exception of an alias of the rowid, e.g. the id column, or the rowid itself ), any type of data in any type of column. Which other databases typically do not allow.

Furthermore, the column type itself is highly flexible. That is you could specify virtually any type e.g. `the_column ridiculoustype` and SQLite will make the type NUMERIC (the default/drop through type) in this case (see 3.1 in the link for the rules for assigning a type affinity).

You should perhaps have a read of https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html